# How to set position of combobox in c# using silverlight5

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, combobox, silverlight-5.0

I am c# and silverlight beginner and i have a situation where i dynamically create combo box and add it in list.

```
if (p.Component.Type == "Combo")
  {
    var cb = new ComboBox();
    foreach (var item in p.Component.Attributes.Items)
      {
        cb.Items.Add(item);  //These item contains a l0,15,45,60 to select through combo box

      }
    result.Add(cb);                    
  }
```

I have many other things like "TextBlock","TextBox" etc. things to add in this list. Suppose i also have to add this TextBlock in same list with one more if condition like this :

```
 if (true)
 {
     var txtblk = new TextBlock();
     txtblk.Text = "Max Amount";
     result.Add(txtblk);
  }
```

Now the outout obtained is like this : 
[image]
 I mean it is always at Top=Left=0. (I mean they overlaps)

Now question is how to give these GUI elements different  position in the same list ? Please do not hesitate to ask me if you still don't understand the question.

**Note: I am using silverlight5**
My xaml code is (My container is canvas) :

```
<UserControl x:Class="RenderingTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:this="clr-namespace:RenderingTest.Converters"
             xmlns:sdh="clr-namespace:RenderingTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <this:MyValueConverter x:Key="TabConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green">
        <sdh:MyItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabList, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Gray">  </Canvas>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Width="150" Background="red" Height="100" Canvas.Left="10"  Canvas.Top="100"  >
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </sdh:MyItemsControl>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

EDIT: I have added the photo of GUI which is supposed to be achieved and also the xml i deserialized(which i am sure that it is properly deserialized i can see that on debugging) (here Parameter is parent class)

EDIT2 (after thbe new answer):

```
My parameter.cs class is:
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

using System.Runtime;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections;
namespace RenderingTest
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "parameter")]
    public class Parameter
    {
        [XmlElement("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("label")]
        public string Label { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("unit")]
        public string Unit { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("component")]
        public Component Component { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ViewModel.cs is : (please note that in ReadParameterXML() i pass the xml string in its parameter from MainPage.cs class)

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Xml;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;


namespace RenderingTest
{
    public class viewModel : GenericViewModel
    {

        private ObservableCollection<Parameter> tabList;
        public ObservableCollection<Parameter> TabList
        {

            get { return tabList; }
            set
            {
                tabList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TabList");
            }
        }


        #region Constructor
        public viewModel()        
        {
            tabList = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();
        }
        #endregion

        public void ReadParameterXML(String xmlstring)
        {


            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Parameter));
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlstring));
            Parameter parameter = (Parameter)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            foreach (var item in parameter.Component.Attributes.Items)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item);
            }
            tabList.Add(parameter);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Component.Type);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Name);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Label);
            Debug.WriteLine(parameter.Unit);
        }

    }
}
```

MyConverter.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Ink;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RenderingTest.Converters
{
    public class MyValueConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            ICollection<Parameter> list = value as ICollection<Parameter>;
            List<UIElement> result = new List<UIElement>();    
                if (list != null)
                {
                    foreach (Parameter p in list)
                    {                
                        if (p.Component.Type == "Combo")
                        {
                            StackPanel st = new StackPanel()
                            {
                                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal
                            };

                            var txtblk = new TextBlock();
                            var txtblk2 = new TextBox();
                            txtblk.Text = p.Label;
                            var cb = new ComboBox();
                            foreach (var item in p.Component.Attributes.Items)
                            {
                                cb.Items.Add(item);  //These item contains a l0,15,45,60 to select through combo box                                
                            }
                            cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Count - 1;
                            txtblk2.Text = cb.SelectedValue.ToString() +" millions";
                            st.Children.Add(txtblk);
                            st.Children.Add(cb);
                            st.Children.Add(txtblk2);
                         //  Canvas.SetTop(cb, itemHeight * i++);
                            result.Add(st);
                        }
                    }
                }
            return(result);
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        #endregion

    }
}
```

MainPage.Xaml is

```
<UserControl x:Class="RenderingTest.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:this="clr-namespace:RenderingTest.Converters"
             xmlns:sdh="clr-namespace:RenderingTest"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <this:MyValueConverter x:Key="TabConverter"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>



    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Green">
        <sdh:MyItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TabList, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TabConverter}}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Canvas Background="Gray"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Width="150" Background="red" Height="100" Canvas.Left="50"  Canvas.Top="100"  >
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border> 
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </sdh:MyItemsControl>
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

Comment: What is the type of `result` in your code above?

Comment: @Mashton List<UIElement>

Comment: ... and how do you then place UI elements onto your canvas? I see that you have an `ItemsSource` binding for your `MyItemsControl`, but presumably that isn't dealing with every `UIElement` you are placing?

Comment: @Mashton I think you are right, This is the reason  that Canvas.SetTop and left are not woirking. Butr how to do it for rendering every UIElement ? I am beginner for xaml and c# could you please help me ?

Comment: My experience with xaml and Silverlight is in an MVVM way and keeping UI and data separate using binding, so I don't have huge experience with what you are trying to achieve. If I was trying to do that I'd still approach it from a position of "I have a base layout I need to achieve, and it is just the particulars of the UI elements that will change". With that in mind I'd mark in Xaml areas, as you have with the list control, and then use binding to populate that list with the particular controls I want to layout. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Mashton if yo see Viewmodel :       public viewModel()        
        {
            tabList = new ObservableCollection<Parameter>();
        }

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some of the [built-in panel controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754152%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Choosing one of these and using it correctly is a good starting point to creating a layout for your view.  A good one to start with is the StackPanel -- that adds each child control underneath the previous one.

Right now you're using the Canvas panel, which could also work, but you are not using it correctly.  A Canvas needs each child element to define its `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` attached properties.

You're also making your life more difficult by using code-behind to construct a UI, rather than using XAML.  You might want research data binding ([starter example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602280%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)), which is the core of Silverlight, before you undertake to build an app.

---

**Edit**

Here are two minimal examples of how you would position your items.

**Option 1**

Use a panel that automatically places its children:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <StackPanel Background="Gray" />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

**Option 2**

If you're sure you want to use a Canvas, then you'll need to set `Canvas.Left` and/or `Canvas.Top` on each of the children.  Here's a basic example of how, using `Canvas.SetTop`:

```
int i=0;
double itemHeight = 30;

if (p.Component.Type == "Combo")
{
    var cb = new ComboBox();
    foreach (var item in p.Component.Attributes.Items)
    {
        cb.Items.Add(item);  //These item contains a l0,15,45,60 to select through combo box
    }
    Canvas.SetTop(cb, itemHeight * i++);
    result.Add(cb);                    
} 
var txtblk = new TextBlock();
txtblk.Text = "Max Amount";
Canvas.SetTop(txtblk, itemHeight * i++);
result.Add(txtblk);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my situation is like i need to use c# code only. because i have deserialized xml and i am using objects created on deserializing xml which are in c#.

Comment: @user234839 gotcha -- in that case see my edit above (2 options).

Comment: Thanks let me implement (will comeback soon to mark it accepeted if it works)

Comment: No its still the same

Comment: It just changes the line. I mean this time textblock is in first line and combo box is in another line. Just that.

Comment: That's because the code given is setting the `Top` of each UI element. If you want to set the `Left` then you'll need to adapt the code. A question though, how do you know whether elements are supposed to be next to each other or on a new line? Does your serialized data contain that information?

Comment: @Mashton Please see the edited question how the GUI and xml which is supposed to be achieved.

Comment: Actually i am obliged to code for these combo box and textblock using c# (using mvvm)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from your edit one possible approach is:

- Create a class which represents your 'parameter' structure. How many different arrangements of this class are you likely to have? Are they all of the form `NameString`, `List<T>`, `UnitsString` or are there other forms? If there are a range of these types then consider how much similarity there actually is, and whether they should be represented as one class or a few derived classes.
- In your ViewModel build up a collection of these `parameter` classes, and bind that collection to an items control in your View
- Define the item template of your items control so that it creates/displays the properties of a parameter class with the appropriate UI elements (i.e. NameString and UnitsString properties displayed in a TextBlock, List displayed in a ComboBox)

But the gist of it is:

- Stop thinking that your data is UI. It isn't. It is data, and should be represented as such ... as a class or classes.
- Then start thinking how best to represent a class of data (or classes of data) with UI elements.
- If there are an unknown number of these classes to show in the UI then you will need to decide what kind of layout should you use ... maybe all of them in a list one after the other? In which case use binding and create a collection of these classes, which will be bound to the `ItemsSource` of an ItemsCollection UI component. Define the item template for this UI component to further bind the properties within your class to a specific kind of UI component appropriate to the kind of property you're dealing with.

Comment: please see the EDIT2 correspdonding to your advice

Comment: Looking much nicer! I don't really know what your `MyItemsControl` does though, so can't really comment on how it uses the `List<UIElement>` it gets from your converter. Ordinarily, I'd bind the ItemsSource to some collection on the VM (as you have done) but not need a converter. Then in the `ItemTemplate`, which corresponds to how you want a single element of that `ItemsSource` to be represented, I'd put down the controls I want and bind them to the properties of that single element.